# Scroll div a set amount up/down

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a jQuery-based solution for scrolling a div up/down at set amount each time triggered by scrolling by mousewheel/click/touch. The only problem with the scroll event is that is fires more than once. What's the best approach for this that will also work for touch-screen devices?

Answer (score 0):

[plugin](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel/) go to this plugin here, may help, not sure

Answer (score 0):

Using the following should work

```
var functionToCallAfterScrolling = function(){
    //Do stuff here
}

$(window).scroll(functionToCallAfterScrolling);
```

Only issue as you said is that the function gets called too many time. To get around that, I use underscorejs's debounce function like this.

Instead of creating the callback function like this

```
var functionToCallAfterScrolling = function(){
    //Do stuff here
}
```

create it like this instead

```
var functionToCallAfterScrolling = _.debounce(function(){
    //Do stuff here
}, 300);
```

What this does is for example if the function gets fired 400 times in one scroll, it only calls the function 
 once, after the 400th time ignoring the firsth 399th times. And it waits 300milliseconds to fire the callback function. You can adjust the wait time to however much suits you.

Just remember that you have to include the underscorejs library.

If you have time, you can just extract the part of the library to provide this functionality.

Url for both links are http://underscorejs.org/#debounce

and [http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) .

Just search for debounce in the second link to get to the function.

Let me know if you need more explanation